# HTML5 and Bootstrap - spaces left on the sides?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie in the world of web development. So, please don't mind if this is a really dumb question but I was doing a project for Free Code Camp and I ran into this problem where I just couldn't get rid of the spaces on left and right.
Here is my pen which I'm coding:
http://codepen.io/K-Jabeen/full/oxOjjQ/

```
<section id="home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <center>
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive"  src="http://ivanmyc.site11.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Web-Development_icon.png" />
        <h1>Pixel Developers</h1>
        <h4>Where pixel perfect web solutions are created...</h4>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </center>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Plz tell me how to solve this.
Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your CSS but my guess would be that you need to set the left and right margin or padding of `body` to 0.

Comment: I just realized I can change the view of your pen to edit view.  The left and right `padding` of `container-fluid` is what's causing your issue.  If you set those to 0, your will get the effect I think you're going for.

Comment: @kst that's messing with Bootstrap's container behavior which is asking for trouble. Either remove the first `container-fluid` altogether or modify the css of `#home`.  See my answer below.

Comment: The word "web development" gets tossed around too easily these days.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `container-fluid` class from the first `div`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

...so it becomes:

```
<div>
```

Alternatively, you can add `margin: 0 -15px;` to the css of `#home`.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good solution... without messing with the Bootstrap markup. I'll try it even though my problem got fixed with turning the padding of .container-fluid to 0. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've seen your updated CodePen and the rule you introduced: `.container-fluid { padding:0; }`. As a rule of thumb you should never modify framework classes - such changes will cause unnecessary trouble later on (and is bad use of the framework itself).

Answer (score 0):

Your main page should have this css added to it:
 margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
The word 'auto' tells the browser to keep the main page centered no matter how wide the screen is. Width 100% tell the browser that image spans the screen from side to side. That should get rid of any side gaps. Make sure your code does not have any existing side margins or padding. If so, set it to zero.